# Get a Lets Encrypt SSL certificate through ZeroSSL for a .ovh.net subdomain

Tags: https, security-certificate, iis, windows, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to set up https connection in one of my API.
I normally make requests to my API through this address: `http://vps******.ovh.net:8090`

I'd like to be able to make HTTPS requests.

I use the [ZeroSSL certificate wizard](https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#crt) to build the certificate.

The problem here is that there been already 100 certificates generated for ovh.net subdomains, cause obviously there's a lot of OVH VPS user that requested let's encrypt certificates.

Is there a way to obtain a free certificate from a trusted authority for domains like `vps******.ovh.net`?

Comment: https://partenaires.uphair.fr  does not redirect so a certificate with this name will work. If `api.uphair.fr` redirects (HTTP) to another URL then you need two certificates one for the source and one for the destination (if both are https:// URLs). For me right now your website just shows a generic Microsoft page (no redirect, no certificate problem)

Comment: For me your api subdomain shows a net error "Server Error in '/' Application." and no certificate.  You should check that the certificate files exist in the .wellknown directory

Comment: Hi Patrick, that's the problem here. I can't generate a certificate for subdomains on ovh from zerossl cause they have a certificate number limit; And obviously some ovh users already generated certificates from zerossl.
How can I generate a free certificate from an authority like zerossl for domains like vps******.ovh.net?

Comment: Hi Steve, this is perfectly normal. I created only a certificate for my api subdomain but I want to know if there's a way to generate one for domains like vps******.ovh.net

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/ doesn't have anything about 100 certificates per domain.   The limit is actually 20 per week.   The only limit of 100 is the number of hostnames that can be included in a single certificate.

Comment: You should also just buy a domain name and get your certificate for that.   It isn't smart to rely on a free subdomain from your hosting company.   That would tie you to that hosting company and make it painful to move for better service or pricing.   Free subdomains are not likely to rank well in search engines either.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm talking about the limit on zerossl wizard, and I confirm you that its not working with sub.ovh.net. I already have a domain (uphair.fr) and a working certificate for https://partenaires.uphair.fr and I would like to put a certificate on api.uphair.fr.

Comment: Maybe there's something I don't undertsand here.

Comment: I must create another domain only for my api ? That sounds pretty weird, I just want to be able to create a subdomain api.uphair.fr from my domain uphair.fr and put a SSL on it this is not possible free of charges ?